# How to integrate facebook comments in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-comments

I'd like to add in facebook comments to my rails blog application. Is there a way to do so and test it on my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use facebook comments, just add the tags in your views.
To test facebook app integration in my development environment I use 127.0.0.1:3000 insted of localhost:3000 in facebook app configurations options.